# Binding of isaac pill effect : "something's wrong..."

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth, the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth+

I was playing Afterbirth+, and used a pill which only said "something's wrong...".

What is the effect of this pill?

Comment: According to your answer, I know why I didn't see it : there already was black creep on the floor I was standing on. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: It doesn't sound like it's the reason for your case, but another possible reason why it might have looked like it did nothing is if you're doing a challenge (specifically the "April's Fool" challenge) which mixes up pill effects. The screen would say "Something's wrong" but the pill effect you get could be "I Found Pills" (i.e., nothing happens).

Comment: I was just playing a hard game with Apollyon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [wiki](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Pills), here is the effect of the "Something's Wrong..." pill:

> Creates a pool of black creep beneath Isaac.

[Black creep](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Creep#Black_Creep) is supposed to slow down the enemies walking on it.